# How to print brandnames of categorynames in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

working with laravel 5.6 and mysql. and I have following `vehicles` table

```
id  name  category  brand    model
1   juy   car       toyota   121
2   gty   van       nissan   caravan
3   bgh   car       bmw      520d
4   hyu   van       ford     max
5   nhj   car       toyota   121
```

in controller I am filtering category as following

```
public function showcategoryname()
    {
      $names = Vehicle::groupBy('category')->select('id', 'category', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as cnt'))->get();  

      return view('welcome')->withNames($names);
    }
```

and printing category in blade file as following,

```
@foreach($names as $name)
                    <tr>
                    <th>{{$name->categoryname}}</th>
                    </span></td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

now I need print brand when I click on categoryname, how can I filter on controller to print brand instead to each category?

Comment: actually I need print each brand with related to each category